# .tlb files not generating in vcxproj .rc file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

On building my project is giving error of not generating (.tlb) file in (vcxproj .rc) file:

> error RC2135: file not found: DocOutPPML.tlb
>     [C:\ElxVC\SRC\OutputConverters\DocOutPPML\DocOutPPMLCHS.vcxproj]

Using visual studio 2010 I converted this proj from vcproj to vcxproj.

Answer (score 4):

You need the resource compiler to have the correct path where to your type library. The place where you can set this is under *resource configuration property* → *general* → *additional include directories*. Just specify there where your type library is.

Answer (score 3):

You have to generate .tlb file.

> /TLBOUT:[path]filename

Where

***path:*** An absolute or relative path specification for where the .tlb file should be created.

***filename:*** Specifies the name of the .tlb file created by the MIDL compiler. No file extension is assumed; specify filename.tlb if you want a .tlb extension.

**Remark**

1. The /TLBOUT option specifies the name and extension of the .tlb
   file.
2. The MIDL compiler is called by the Visual C++ linker when linking
   projects that have the module attribute.
3. If /TLBOUT is not specified, the .tlb file will get its name from
   /IDLOUT filename. If /IDLOUT is not specified, the .tlb file will be
   called vc70.tlb.

**To set this linker option in the Visual Studio development environment**

- Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see
  Setting Visual C++ Project Properties.
- Click the Linker folder.
- Click the Embedded IDL property page.
- Modify the Type Library property.

Comment: thanx for your help , but my problems solve through setting intermediate file, as on rebuild it delete the files of other project creating it....:)

Comment: Sorry ! but I am not understanding what you are saying....can you describe the problem..

Comment: it was an huge project having more than 300 sub projects, automated building is used through msbuild, there are many dependencies relations between different projects, in few cases intermediat directory the option just below output path is same, so on rebuild it delete files of intermediate directly including output of previous projects but builds itself only, which returns error due to missing files, my english is not very much good but good-enough if you want to understand....:)

Comment: problem solved on changing intermediate directories but in one case it is not working, i can change settings consider it like i only have access to project settings not to building script

Comment: oh....I think you should define the Project Dependency from the Property of the Project.

Comment: bro one project is generating the .tlb file other is using, in one case it gives the error of not finding again, but how can i do any of the following solution,
1. set the path for output
2. set the searching directory for tlb....?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the right name for the "(.tlb) file" in the command line:

```
midl <your>.idl /tlb <any>.tlb
```

1. Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see Set
   C++ compiler and build properties in Visual Studio.
2. Click the **Build Events** folder.
3. Click the **Pre-Build Event** property page.
4. Modify the **Command Line** property.

```
echo === Log ===
cd "$(ProjectDir)"
midl.exe DocOutPPML.idl /tlb DocOutPPML.tlb
cd "$(TargetDir)"
echo ===
```